# Android latitude and longitude returns null

Tags: java, android

I am getting a strange error because if I run the app on a real phone,
it doesn't give this error (Android 5.0) . But on the emulator (Android 6.0) it gives me this error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                       Process: com.doppler.stackingcoder.pechhulp, PID: 11424
>                                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                                           at
>   com.doppler.stackingcoder.pechhulp.PechhulpActivity.onLocationChanged(PechhulpActivity.java:171)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.doppler.stackingcoder.pechhulp.PechhulpActivity.onMapReady(PechhulpActivity.java:126)

And this is my PechhulpActivity:

https://gist.github.com/soufyanekaddouri/6e3a3746be137e2680caa32d7bb746d9

Comment: Try this if you are using Fused API https://stackoverflow.com/a/53348535/6667442

Answer (score 1):

With respect to your crash, you are assuming that at least one provider will return a `Location` from `getLastKnownLocation()`. That is not required, on either a device or an emulator. You need to handle the case where all providers return `null` from `getLastKnownLocation()`. This could be by not attempting to use the location. Or, requests location updates, then use the location from the first update.

Comment: Do you have a example for me? I am just a beginner

Comment: @Stackingcoder: Well, I have [this sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/WebKit/GeoWeb2) that requests location updates and also tries to use `getLastKnownLocation()`, though the example is tied into using those with a `WebView`. I have [this sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Internet/Weather) that is a more conventional app but only requests (and uses) location updates.